# Using bootstrap rows, cols, flex and ordering items for a specific collapse arrangement

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I would like to display a series of logos on a site that I'm building that flow nicely with the bootstrap responsive columns. The idea is that clicking on each of the logos opens up a related description below by pushing down the line below using the collapse method. It needs to work without knowing the amount of items and without restricting the layout to a set number of elements to a line. ( the markup is written with a php loop ).

I've got some semi-working code but the problems are that it will be limited due to the amount of order classes in bootstrap. And also, it's jumpy and I feel it's not an elegant solution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row mx-5 mt-5 mt-md-5 d-flex flex-row">     

    <?php 
    $c = 12/12; $c_sm = 12/12; $c_md =12/ 6; $c_lg = 12/4; $c_xl = 12/3;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) :
    $order = ceil( $i / $c );
    $order_sm = ceil( $i / $c_sm );
    $order_md = ceil( $i / $c_md );
    $order_lg = ceil( $i / $c_lg );
    $order_xl = ceil( $i / $c_xl );
    ?>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-1 order-md-<?= $order_md ?> order-lg-<?= $order_lg ?> order-xl-<?= $order_xl ?> border p-3">
        <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#description-<?= $i ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="logo-<?= $i ?>" >
            <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">Logo <?= $i ?></p>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse col-12 order-1 order-md-<?= $order_md + 1 ?> order-lg-<?= $order_lg + 1 ?> order-xl-<?= $order_xl + 1 ?> border font-italic p-4" id="description-<?= $i ?>">
        <p class="m-0">Description <?= $i ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php endfor ?>

</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for a more elegant solution? One that is future proof and isn't limited by number of items. Preferably one that doesn't need much php class writing. Also.. do you have any suggestions why this solution is glitchy and not smooth?